# http request denied without explanation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, httprequest, cheerio

Building a scraping project with node, express, request and cheerios.  Turns out only some websites return the request like indeed. Grocery store sites like Walmart don't return even an error. Is it because it is blocked? Checked for robot.text. Negative.

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const url = 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=web+developer&l=Salt+Lake+City%2C+UT'

app.get('/scrape', (req, res)=>{
request(url, (err, res, body)=>{
  if(err){console.log("this website wont talk to you")}
      console.log(body);
});
res.send('Check your console!')
});


app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
  console.log("server is spinning on port " + PORT);
})

exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: You do know Indeed has an RSS feed? That would be easier to parse

Comment: I understand you need to scrape a website...which then gives a page & data & further pagination... I would suggest use the write tool to scrap

Comment: Try using `curl -v` to examine the exchange with the server.

Comment: What HTTP status code does it return? I'd be very surprised if there's nothing at all and that may be informative. Try logging `err` to the console.

Comment: yes this is just the first few lines of code. ideal is to scrape site like say, walmart, for say milk prices for today. Thats where it is not returning data.

Comment: You could also try sending a request to RequestBin to see what actually gets sent

Comment: so you meant to say.... the indeed URL is returning results but not the walmart URl...could you share a walmart URL

Comment: well this is the one that does not return results "https://www.smithsfoodanddrug.com/search?query=cheese&page=2&tab=0"

Comment: I checked the urls u mentioned. For `indeed` we are getting response, but for `walmart` we are getting `ECONNRESET`. `Error: read ECONNRESET`  says that your `connection/request` got cancelled on the `TCP/IP` level. This may have many reasons but basically your request is configured correctly. It might just be the server you are sending the requests to which is resetting the connection.

Comment: Attempting to scrape web pages with raw requests is fine in theory but you have to do lots of work to handle redirects and dynamic asynchronous rendering. You are better off using a scriptable headless browser like https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer and querying the page contents after a render.

Comment: The example code above was just to check access. I checked the puppeteer and it seems like there are blockers on the particular website to avoid scrapers.